# Responsive table: move cell to new line if table too small

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, media-queries

I'm in a situation where I **need** to use a `table`, but I also want it to be **responsive**.

For some point `under max-width: 500px`, I would like to convert my third `<td>` elements to second line with `100% width` and others with `50% width` each.

I know that with `display: block` on the `<td>`'s I can place them beneath each other, something I will do eventually. But I want that step in between.

```css
table {
    height: 400px;
    width: 100%;
}
table tr td:nth-child(1) {
    background-color: red;
}
table tr td:nth-child(2) {
    background-color: green;
}
table tr td:nth-child(3) {
    background-color: blue;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 500px) {
    table tr td:nth-child(3) {
        background-color: pink;
        clear: both;
        display: block;
        width: 100%;
    }
    table tr td:nth-child(1), table tr td:nth-child(2) {
        display: block;
        width: 50%;
    }
}
```

```html
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

[(Fiddle version)](http://jsfiddle.net/frk7jbvu/)

I already tried different `display` variaties like `inline-block`.
Is this at all possible? And preferably without JS?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Inline-block works if you deal with the whitespace around the cells so that two 50%-width elements fit:

```
table {
    ...
    border-spacing: collapse;
}
td {
    padding: 0;
}
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/frk7jbvu/3)**

Notice that I've removed some of the unnecessary styles from your third cell.